# listview refresh aynctask in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I am unable to refresh my listview. I know there are lots of help available for this. But I am unable to get my listview refreshed.

Lemme edit my code a little bit showing the AsyncTask

There are two Activities. The first Activity is having the list view to see what is being shared and the second activity has an edit text box (to input inorder to share) and a button. On clicking the button, it returns me the string which is the json response and I need to add this in the previous activity.

Now the problem is, when I refresh the first page fully hitting the server it gets the response but this is not what I want. It should not go back to the server. It should simply add in the list view adapter.

I have commented the code in the PostExecute(). I have tried the everyway but it is not reflecting.

```
public class ShareAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<EventsStreamBean>> {

    public ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(EventStreamActivity.this);

    String success_share_val;

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<EventsStreamBean> doInBackground(
            String... result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(result[0].toString());

        success_share_val = jsonobj.getString(Constants.SUCCESS);


        //checks the success value
        if(success_share_val.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {            

         JSONArray events_stream_share_array = jsonobj.getJSONArray("streamArray");

         if(events_stream_share_array.length() > 0) {


                 for(int i=0; i<events_stream_share_array.length(); i++) {

                     EventsStreamBean events_stream_bean = new EventsStreamBean();

                     JSONObject events_stream_object = events_stream_share_array.getJSONObject(i);

                     events_stream_bean.setStreamId(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.STREAM_ID));
                     events_stream_bean.setStreamType(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.STREAM_TYPE));

                     events_stream_bean.setUserId(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.USER_ID));
                     events_stream_bean.setUserName(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.USER_NAME));
                     events_stream_bean.setUserType(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.USER_TYPE));
                     events_stream_bean.setUserAvatar(events_stream_object.getString(Constants.USER_AVATAR));

                     arraylist_events_stream.add(events_stream_bean);

                 }
         }else {
             Log.i("Test", "No Events Streams Available");
         }

        }

        }catch(Exception e) {}



        return arraylist_events_stream;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        this.pd.setMessage("Loading....");
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); 
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        this.pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<EventsStreamBean> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(this.pd.isShowing()) {
            this.pd.dismiss();
        }


        Toast.makeText(EventStreamActivity.this, "Post shared successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new EventsStreamAsyncTask().execute(temp_val);



        /*runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                //EventStream_Customadapter adapter = (EventStream_Customadapter) list_view.getAdapter();
                //adapter.clearData();

                adapter.updateData(result);
                //adapter = new EventStream_Customadapter(EventStreamActivity.this, arraylist_events_stream);
                //list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });*/

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the adapter code?

Comment: @Appu: There a lot many things in the adapter. It would not be possible for me to show the adapter code

Comment: Well, that's fine. I have asked because to ensure whether you change the data in the adapter before calling notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: @Appu: There are two Asynctasks so I am setting the adapter twice you can say..

Comment: @Appu: So I tried clearing the first arraylist and then updating it with the new one..but invain

Comment: Try 'setAdapter' first before 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();'.....might work not sure..!!

Comment: But have your called your youradapter.clear() before populating new data in listview

Comment: @anuja why have you put Thread into Async Task? may be you got exception in some device according to my knowledge. I have done same think as you are doing and I have create adapter object in Inbackground() method and setAdapter in postexecute() method. and it's work fine for me.

Comment: @Jeet: I am using BaseAdapter and there is no clear method in it

Answer (score 0):

1. You should call setAdapter() only once in your entire code.
2. Then add a method in your adapter that adds more data when you want to add more data or sets adapter item.

   ```
   public void addMoreData(List<String> newItems) {
   this.list.addAll(newItems);
   }
   public void setList(List<String> newList) {
   this.list = newList;
   }
   ```
3. Call notifyDataSetChanged() after you set new list or add more data.

Answer (score 0):

as per what you want to achieve there is no need for you to use threads
 have a look at the following link it shows how to do it in the same activity

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-items-to-listview-in-android/

In this they have done it in a single activity. if you want to do it with 2 activities let me know i will tell you how to do it.